# How to control the draw order of nodes in Networkx's draw?

Tags: python, graph, networkx, graph-theory

I want to show distrubution of pagerank in a dataset using a figure. I want to highlight nodes with higher pagerank. To do this I colored every node based on the pagerank score. However when I try to draw the graph I get the following image. The nodes with high pagerank are obstructed by nodes with low pagerank. I want to draw nodes with low pagerank first so that nodes with high pagerank will appear on the top. Is it possible to do this? If not are there any workarounds to highlight these nodes?

Link to dataset: https://snap.stanford.edu/data/p2p-Gnutella08.html

[image: Pagerank]

```py
import networkx as nx
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

# Import graph from edge list
Graphtype = nx.DiGraph()
graph = nx.read_edgelist(
        'path/to/dataset',
        create_using=Graphtype,
        nodetype=int
    )
method = 'pagerank'

# Calculate pagerank and set as node attribute
model = nx.pagerank(graph, alpha=0.85)
nx.set_node_attributes(graph, model, method)

# Convert to undirected graph
u_graph = nx.to_undirected(graph)

# Get the largest component
largest_component = max(nx.connected_components(u_graph), key=len)
u_graph = u_graph.subgraph(largest_component)

# Generate colors based on node attribute
colors = [u_graph.nodes[n][method] for n in list(u_graph.nodes())]
pos = nx.spring_layout(u_graph)

# Draw edges and nodes
plt.figure(figsize=(15, 15))
nx.draw_networkx_edges(u_graph, pos)
nc = nx.draw_networkx_nodes(u_graph, pos, node_color=colors, node_size=10)

# Configure plot
plt.colorbar(nc)
plt.title(method)
plt.show()
```

Comment: I! Great question. The code you included in the question is not very helpful, though, as it is not reproducible. In particular, if I try to run it, I get error `name 'path_names' is not defined`

Comment: I think you can use [`draw_networkx_nodes`](https://networkx.org/documentation/stable/reference/generated/networkx.drawing.nx_pylab.draw_networkx_nodes.html#networkx.drawing.nx_pylab.draw_networkx_nodes) repeatedly with partial `nodelist`s to draw only a subset of the nodes at a time. If you provide your graph in a more reproducible manner (i.e, hard-coding the list of nodes and edges and colours in the code), then I can fiddle a bit around with it and provide a nicer answer.

Comment: @Stef It's a helper method to fetch the path to dataset. It can be replaced with the absolute path to the edgelist file.

Comment: What edgelist file? I don't have an edgelist file. That's my point. The picture you included is very helpful to understand your question. The code snippet is not helpful at all, because we cannot run it, because it relies on variables that are not defined in the snippet you've shown us, and on files which are on your computer. If you do include code in a question, please make it a [mre]. Otherwise it's not useful at all.

Comment: @Stef I already provided the edgelist file on my original question. Please check the dataset link I have provided. It's the exact dataset I have used to generate the image in the question.

Comment: @Stef edited the code snipped to make it more clear

Comment: No, I am not going to download the dataset that you linked. Why would I do that? Your question is not about this dataset. It's about how to decide which nodes appear on the foreground and which nodes appear in the background if nodes are too close together. I already gave you a suggestion on how to do that. I also made a suggestion to read page [mre], so that you can rewrite the question in a self-contained way that is more likely to attract answers. The big dataset you linked is not relevant to the question.